# It gives the right answer and sometimes gives the wrong answer

Tags: python, loops, math

```
print("Hello, and welcome to the Maths quiz!/n")

#Asks user for name - 05/03/2015
name = input("What is your name?")

#This will import random to generate random functions
import random

#This is a variable for score
#It has been set to 0 at the start of the program
score = 0

#This creates an array containing the mathematical operators
#that this quiz will use
ops = ['+','-','*']

#A loop has been set for 0 - 10
for x in (0,10):
    #This is variable has been set to the operator of the equation that
    #uses the random function and will choose a random operator from the
    #array containing the operators made earlier
    op = random.choice(ops)
    if op == '+':
        left1 = random.randint(1,100)
        right1 = random.randint(1,100)
        print (str(left1) + op + str(right1))
        answer  = eval(str(left1) + op + str(right1))
        guess = input("")
        if guess == answer:
            print("Correct!")
            score += 1
        else:
            print ("Incorrect")
    elif op == '-':
        left2 = random.randint(1,100)
        right2 = random.randint(1,100)
        print (str(left2) + op + str(right2))
        answer1 = eval(str(left2) + op + str(right2))
        guess1 = int(input(""))
        if answer1 == guess1:
            print("Correct!")
            score += 1
        else:
            print("Incorrect")
    elif op == '*':
        left3 = random.randint(1,100)
        right3 = random.randint(1,100)
        print (str(left3) + op + str(right3))
        answer2 = eval(str(left3) + op + str(right3))
        guess2 = input("")
        if answer2 == guess2:
            print("Correct!")
            score += 1
        else:
            print("Incorrect")
    else:
        break

print (score)
```

When I do this, it generates a random quiz that only loops twice, even though I want it to loop 10 times. Also, it sometimes give the right answer and sometimes the wrong answer. For example:

```
Hello, and welcome to the Maths quiz!/n
What is your name?j
95*3
285
Incorrect
35-46
-11
Correct!
```

What I want for this to do is generate random arithmetic questions using the addition, subtraction and multiplication operators. Plus, for it to loop 10 times and give a score out of 10 at the end.

Comment: Why are you doing exactly the same thing inside your three if blocks? Surely the whole point of defining the op generically and using `eval` is so that you don't need to repeat the code. You shouldn't need the if/elif statements at all.

Comment: @iced: they are doing their homework themselves, and are only asking for why it isn't working.

Comment: @iced: really, as far as homework (or in this case GCSE exam) questions are concerned, this isn't all that bad.

Comment: I have no idea what GCSE exam is, but I have strong believe that point of any exam is to test one particular examinee, not SO community.
though I agree this question (and code in it) is way better written than majority of homework questions.

Comment: @iced: GCSE is a UK highschool (14-16 years old) national examination, this is the coding component of the Computing GCSE, see [the list of 2015 problems](http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/2gawvg/gcse_computing_programming_tasks_14_16_year_olds/). This is Choice 2, which includes some more work.

Comment: @iced: I understood you are allowed to use the internet for research; I do not know how much help you are allowed to get however. As usual, others have just posted the requirements and then wait for someone to write the code for them, which we then close and downvote. So by comparison, this user at least made a viable attempt at solving the task first.

Comment: if you want to help him - better explain how to move 3 equal if branches to single function ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are not always converting the input to an integer.

When `op == '*'` or `op == '+'`, you try to compare against the string returned from `input()`:

```
guess2 = input("")
```

String comparisons to numbers are never equal. For `op == '-'` you correctly convert the answer to an integer first:

```
guess1 = int(input(""))
```

Your loop is broken too; you are looping over a tuple containing two values:

```
for x in (0, 10):
```

rather than over a range:

```
for x in range(0, 10):
```

You'd be far better off avoiding so much repetition in your code; calculate the expression outcome and ask for the answer in *one* place; that way there are fewer places to make mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
for x in (0,10):
    ...
```

runs the code (`...`) two times: one time with `x` set to 0, and a second time with `x` set to 10.

What you really want is this:

```
for x in range(10):
    ...
```

Then `x` will be 0, 1, ..., 9 and the code runs 10 times.